# ggplot2 adding standard deviation of rolling mean to scatter graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, moving-average, standard-deviation

I am struggling with mapping the standard deviation of a rolling mean onto a scatter graph. Very new to R, using ggplot2 and have successfully plotted the raw data and the moving average but struggling to add on the standard deviation. Any advice? Thanks

```r
    Mar<- ggplot(NG_data2,
       mapping = aes(x = Varve,
                     y = Aragonite))+
      geom_line(size = 1, colour = "black")+
      geom_ma(mapping = NULL,
          data = NG_data2,
          position = "identity",
          show.legend = NA,
          inherit.aes = TRUE,
          ma_fun = SMA,
          n = 30,
          wilder = FALSE,
          ratio = NULL,
          v = 1,
          wts = 3,
          colour = "red")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's currently possible to get standard deviation from `tidyquant` the way it does the moving avg, but it should be possible to calculate these in other ways, and feed them into ggplot. For instance, rolling mean and sd could be calculated using the `slider` package and `dplyr` like so:

```
library(dplyr); library(slider); library(lubridate)

#storms is a dataset that comes with dplyr. Here I grab a piece from one storm:
storms[storms$name == "Frederic",1:10] %>%

  # here I use lubridate::ymd to create timestamps combining a few columns; 
  #  won't be needed if your data already has a date column
  mutate(time = ymd_h(paste(year, month, day, hour))) %>%

  # here's the guts: slider::slide_inded_dbl takes a variable, an indexing
  #  column (time here), a function (mean or sd), and an index window
  mutate(ma = slide_index_dbl(wind, time, mean, .before = days(2)),
         sd = slide_index_dbl(wind, time, sd, .before = days(2))) %>%

  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = wind)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(aes(y = ma), lty = "dotted") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = ma - sd, ymax = ma + sd), alpha = 0.1)
```

[image]